# English alphabet recognition in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I am planning to do a semester project on English alphabet recognition using Python. I am using Python for the first time. What are the tools and methodologies needed? Please help.

Comment: If the user draws an 'A', the application should decide that it is the English alphabet 'A'. I don't know where to begin with and the tools required for this. I seriously need help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear and I suggest you rephrase it or risk having it put on hold.

However, if you mean checking whether a character in a string is a letter, you can use the built-in `isaplha()` method.

## Examples:

```
>>> 'a'.isalpha()
True

>>> 'x'.isalpha()
True

>>> my_char = 'd'
>>> my_char.isalpha()
True

>>> '1'.isalpha()
False

>>> my_var = '#'
>>> my_var.isalpha()
False
```

Comment: I am familiar with the basics in Python. I want to do my semester project on building an application that can take input as image and output as character represented by that image. Suppose if you draw an 'A' the program must display 'A'.